# is ether itself an ERC20 token?

Tags: tokens

Can I treat ether as an ERC20 token? If so, what is the ehter contract address?
For example I would like to stream ether to another account. But I need to provide contract address of ether for that.

Comment: [Here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc0829421c1d260bd3cb3e0f06cfe2d52db2ce315#code) is another example of ERC20 wrapper contract for Ether, called `EtherToken`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ether is not an ERC20 token - however, the [WETH](https://weth.io/) [contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2) creates Wrapped Ether, which is an ERC20 token backed 1:1 by Ether.

Comment: I suspected there will be some hack strapped on to make it work. The whole ehterium feels like horse shoed or strapped on to make it work.